# Pandas using Datetimeindex and loc

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I'm using `loc` to get the indices under certain conditions. Then I take timedeltas of those indices and try to access my dataframe again with those two indices. I get the following error:

> "Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-16 17:59:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Zeitstempel', freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp"

My code:

```
idx_open = df.loc[(df.Status == 'SR_OPEN')&(df.count_open == 1)&(df.count_close == 0)].index
n = 100
window = pd.Timedelta('15min')

begin = idx_open[n:n+1]
begin_1 = begin - window
begin_2 = begin + window
df.loc[begin_1:begin_2]
```

Comment: I assume `begin` should be a Timestamp; so why don't you take `begin = idx_open[n]`?

Comment: Actually, this worked perfectly and made my code a little shorter too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it seems like a type problem. Try to cast your dates:

```
begin_1 = pd.to_datetime(begin) - window
begin_2 = pd.to_datetime(begin) + window
df.loc[begin_1:begin_2]
```

Comment: I somehow need to convert the begin to a timestamp. Using `begin_1 = pd.to_datetime(begin) - window` still has DatetimeIndex has  dtype='datetime64[ns]'

Comment: Then, try to use pd.Timestamp(begin). See options here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html